# Filter geofabrik to Mapbox Style

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, osmfilter, osmium

GeoFabrik's extracts - as expected - have a massive amount of unnecessary information for most applications. Filtering this information is a critical step to decrease the map's size, especially for mobile uses. OsmFilter or Osmium seem to be the main tools for the job, however, the list of nodes, lines and so on in OSM is simply overwhelming. Could one method simply be retrieving the used named layers in [Mapbox Strets v7](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v7/) (for example), and remove everything else?

On a side note, it seems that [converting tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283181/workflow-to-create-global-mapbox-tileset) might be necessary, is there any comprehensive list/guide on these subjects?

Comment: You talk about "decreasing the map's size for mobile" so I guess you're talking about vector maps created from OSM data, and I guess you're also talking about Mapbox's toolchain for creating those.  Does it really not drop superfluous data from generated vector tiles?  The corresponding tools for raster tiles would tend to do that so that the rendering database is no bigger than needs be.  Can you add a bit more info about what specific problems you've found and what you've tried so far?

Comment: @SomeoneElse you are absolutely right, I am talking about porting OSM data to Mapbox style maps - such as mapbox-streets-v8 - by generating mvtiles. As far as I could find, and I'm fairly new to this, there is no mapbox supplied toolchain to achieve this, I could only find OpenMapTile's.